# How to send data to bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm trying to learn Bloc state management and developing a simple app to learn.
when the user types anything in a `TextField` that text will be displayed under the field.

[image]

and now I'm sending the text field controller to the bloc file by declaring the controller globally.

```
final textController = TextEditingController();
```

but I want to know if there is any way to send the controller value to the bloc file from UI code (without global declaring)

Comment: You can update your bloc data within `onChanged` method on `TextField` Widget.

Comment: Refer to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pjzvCDc4L8, You can take value from UI to Bloc using Event Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the below code

[flutter_bloc: 7.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

Solution 1

Bloc Class

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'demo_event.dart';
part 'demo_state.dart';

class DemoBloc extends Bloc<DemoEvent, DemoState> {
  DemoBloc() : super(DemoNoInputState());

  @override
  Stream<DemoState> mapEventToState(DemoEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetInput) {
      yield* _mapGetInputEventToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<DemoState> _mapGetInputEventToState(GetInput event) async* {
    // showInputfromBloc() {
    //   // Call an API
    // }

    // showInputfromBloc();

    yield DemoInitial(inputText: event.inputText);
  }
}
```

Event Class

```
part of 'demo_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class DemoEvent {}

class GetInput extends DemoEvent {
  String inputText;

  GetInput(this.inputText);
}
```

State

```
part of 'demo_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class DemoState {}

class DemoInitial extends DemoState {
  String? inputText;

  DemoInitial({this.inputText});
}

class DemoNoInputState extends DemoState {}
```

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final DemoBloc demoBloc = DemoBloc();

  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    demoBloc.close();
    textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Enter Input',
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
                hintText: 'Enter Input',
              ),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<DemoBloc, DemoState>(
              bloc: demoBloc,
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is DemoInitial) {
                  return Text(
                    '${state.inputText}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  );
                } else if (state is DemoNoInputState) {
                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          demoBloc.add(GetInput(textEditingController.text));
        },
        child: const Center(child: Text("Result")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Solution 2

[image: Reult]

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final DemoBloc demoBloc = DemoBloc();

  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    demoBloc.close();
    textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Enter Input',
            ),
            BlocBuilder<DemoBloc, DemoState>(
              bloc: demoBloc,
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is DemoInitial) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        controller: textEditingController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Input',
                          hintText: 'Enter Input',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          demoBloc.add(GetInput(textEditingController.text));
                        },
                      ),
                      if (textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty)
                        Text(
                          '${state.inputText}',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Bloc Class

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'demo_event.dart';
part 'demo_state.dart';

class DemoBloc extends Bloc<DemoEvent, DemoState> {
  DemoBloc() : super(DemoInitial());

  @override
  Stream<DemoState> mapEventToState(DemoEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetInput) {
      yield* _mapGetInputEventToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<DemoState> _mapGetInputEventToState(GetInput event) async* {
    yield DemoInitial(inputText: event.inputText);
  }
}
```

State

```
part of 'demo_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class DemoState {}

class DemoInitial extends DemoState {
  String? inputText;

  DemoInitial({this.inputText});
}
```